# Unable to Locate DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have game on wp 8.1 and win 8.1. It works fine in debug mode, but in release I'm getting error on loading. It's crashing before window initialization and startup app.

> First-chance exception at 0x771C8F05 (ntdll.dll) in Game.Windows.exe:
>   0xC0000135: Unable to Locate DLL.

I can't understand, what's wrong. I've checked third party dll's (SDL2.dll, etc.) for both configurations - nothing suspicious. What I'm missing?

Comment: Are you mixing up 64bit and 32bit DLLs?

Comment: One quick way is to use SysInternals ProcMon (http://live.sysinternals.com/ProcMon.exe) and filter on Operation is Load Image and Process Name is Game.Windows.exe, and compare between working/broken. Alternatively on the broken one set a filter on Path ends with .DLL and Process Name is Game.Windows.exe - Note it will be normal to see some failures here, the key is to look for a failure that is never found.

Comment: @Grantly, no. All dll's were built for win32.

Comment: @BoJIHanpocmombI OK cheers.  And your Debug and Release are both set for 32 bit?  (A long shot...)  ... Are you using optimizations?  Perhaps try switching them off one at a time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a problem, you can use a free tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Load in your exe file built from your release configuration and it will tell you what are you missing. To solve "DLL hell" issues, such a tool is a must.

Comment: Ah! I've forgot about this tool. Finally found that SDL2.dll was built with dependency of msvcr120d_app.dll. Thanks a lot!